# To get controls inside static function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am calling function in codebehind from javascript using webservice.

```
function  GetAdmissionType()
        {
            InitComponents();
            var type="";
            type=document.getElementById(dlAdmissionType.id).value;
             document.getElementById(hdnAdmissionType.id).value=document.getElementById(dlAdmissionType.id).value;

             else if(type=="2")
             {
                   InitComponents();
                   ViewResettingPanel()
                   makeFavorite(1);

             }
    }



       function makeFavorite(id) {
    PageMethods.SaveInfo(id, CallSuccess, CallFailed);
}

// This will be Called on success
function CallSuccess(res, id) {
alert(destCtrl);
}

// This will be Called on failure
function CallFailed(res) {
alert(res.get_message());
}
```

Following is my code in codebehind

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void SaveInfo(String Id)
    {

       //to get textbox in form
    }
```

Problem is iam not getting controls in aspx page in SaveInfo.Can anybody help to access controls in form inside saveinfo?

Answer (score 1):

Static page methods cannot get the page's control tree.  (They don't receive ViewState)

You will need to use an `UpdatePanel`.

You can make an `asp:Button` inside a `<div style="display:none>` with a regular `Click` event, make an `UpdatePanel` triggered by the button, and use Javascript to simulate a click of the button.

Alternatively, you could send the values of the controls that you need as parameters to your page method in Javascript.  This will be more efficient than using an `UpdatePanel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Your WebMethod is static, meaning it exists once, for all instances of your page class.  It has no notion of any individual instance of your Page.

If you need to post your page back, you'll need to actually use postbacks, and not web service calls.